# What is the fastest eigen decomposition "serial" algorithm for symmetric matrices?

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came to know about:

"Inderjit Singh Dhillon thesis A New O(n2) Algorithm for the Symmetric Tridiagonal Eigenvalue/Eigenvector Problem"

which the Apache Math Commons implemented once (around their version 2.0).

But such article is kind of old; are there newer approaches besides the well known tridiagonalization + QL/QR approach that is taken by most libraries today? This question is motivated by the following JIRA task that I created for Apache Math Commons:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-1334

Where it seems that the specialized version they use to have (Mr. Dhillon's algorithm + other stuff), is far better than the tridiagonal+implicit QL approach they are taken today (speaking about symmetric case of course).

So, if an "old" algorithm could beat the standard practice today; I feel that I may be missing overall perspective. Would like to know a comprehensive survey of all serial algorithms for symmetric eigen problem please; so I can check which ones made its way into libraries.

Recent survey articles are much appreciated.

Thanks.

PS: Please beware I am not interested in parallel/distributed versions, just serial ones.